# Can we use COPY command to load files from FTP server?

Tags: cassandra, ftp, cqlsh

We have a scenario where we need to run a Cassandra COPY command get file from FTP server and load data in to Cassandra Tables?

Answer (score 1):

**No, you can't directly load remote csv with COPY command**

You have to download the csv file from FTP server then you can load the file. But if you are using linux you can do this with `curl+cqlsh`

```
curl 'csv_url' | cqlsh node_ip -u username -p username -k keyspace_name -e "copy table_name from stdin with header = true"
```

Example :

```
curl 'https://pastebin.com/raw/Re6JPaX4' | cqlsh 192.168.65.199 -u cassandra -p cassandra -k test -e "copy table_name from stdin with header = true"
```

Answer (score -1):

yes it will work 
example : cqlsh "hostname" -u cassandra -p cassandra -e "COPY statement"